# How to read all columns of an excel file into a pandas data frame until a condition is met?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to read an excel file into a pandas data frame. But I only need the columns till a marker called 'End'. This is just a string in a cell in an otherwise empty column, in the excel file. The number of columns before this marker can change in number, so I can't set fixed columns.

What I tried so far was to read the whole excel file into a data frame. Now I'm trying to drop all columns after one column contains the 'End' string or select all columns before the 'End' marker.

How can I achieve this?

Maybe something like this?

`df = df.iloc[:, : df != 'End']`

I tried to find the column containing 'End' like this:

`end = [col for col in df.columns if 'End' in col]`

But the list stays empty.

P.S. Some cells have a background color but contain no content nor formula. Somehow pandas reads them as just empty cells and I can't fill them with na values for some reason. I tried `pd.read_excel(***,  na_values='^\s+$')` and `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` in various variations with no success. Maybe you have an idea how to fix this as well.

EDIT:

The 'End' is located in the first cell of the column. After import into a data frame it reads:

| Unnamed 13 |
| --- |
| End |
| NaN |
| *empty |

With *empty meaning that this cell in the data frame is just blank, and I can't transform into nan. In the Excel file this column has a background color. Maybe that's why pandas gets confused. These empty cell show up wherever the Excel has an empty cell with background color.

[image: Debug View]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you want to find first column containing 'End' and filtering columns from 0 till that column. If so, you could try:

**Sample dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'Column2': [4, 5, 6],
                   'Column_End': [7, 8, 9],
                   'Column3': [10, 11, 12]})
```

**Solution:**

```
end_col = df.columns.get_loc([x for x in df.columns if 'End' in x][-1])
df = df.iloc[:, 0:end_col+1]
```

**Output:**

```
   Column1  Column2  Column_End
0        1        4           7
1        2        5           8
2        3        6           9
```

By using list comprehension we found last column containing 'End' in the name. Then we took position of this column by using `get_loc()` function. When we know the exact position, we filtered certain columns from the dataframe by using `iloc`.

If it's possible that sometimes you have column with 'End' in the document and sometimes don't - you can add an exception for IndexError and assign len(df.columns) to end_col. Then you just get all columns from the document.

**EDIT**

If column names always start from second row in excel you can add `skiprows=1` to `read_excel()` as a parameter and then use the solution I provided. If you want to keep 'Unnamed' columns, but filter through the first row below columns you can do:

```
end_col = df.iloc[0, :].to_list().index([x for x in df.iloc[0, :] if 'End' in x][-1])
```

...and then using iloc as above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As long as the 'End' substring is in a column name this solution works perfectly fine. Unfortunately in my case the substring 'End' is not in the column title. Could you please have a quick look at my solution. ATM it works for me but maybe it could be done in a better way.

Comment: It would be easier if you add some small data sample to your question. Then we could see where 'End' word is located and what is the whole structure.

Comment: The 'End' is located in the first cell of the column. After import it reads:

Unamed: 6
End
*empty
*empty
...

With *empty meaning that this cell in the data frame is just blank and I can't transform into nan. In the excel file this column has a background color. Maybe that's why pandas gets confused.

Comment: "First cell of the column" - do you mean one row below column names? Pandas shouldn't get confused because of a background color. It's just ignored.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I edited my question with a table and a screenshot. Maybe that clears things up a bit.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it now.

Comment: Sorry to bother you one more time. Yes this would work perfectly fine. Unfortunately all the other column names are in the row above. I know, it's confusing, but I didn't create this Excel file, and I'm not allowed to alter it as well.
I can't share the Excel file because it contains restricted costumer data.

But nevertheless, I learned from your answer and think I might come in handy in the future.

Thanks again for your patience. Have a nice week

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found a solution which works for me. The reason why I had to differ from [@Arkadiusz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13340143/arkadiusz) solution is that the `'End'` substring **was not** in the column title of the data frame. Which I didn't make clear in the text of my question. Otherwise, their solution works perfectly fine. This is the code that worked for me in the end:

```
end = df.loc[:, (df == 'End').any()].columns

end_name = end.values[0]

df = df.loc[:, :end_name]
```

EDIT: The empty cells contained empty strings `''`. Using this code:

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s+$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

I was able to fix this issue as well.